# Как расположить список состоящий из 4 элементов в порядке указанном в другом списке? Питон

Tags: python

Допустим
a = [11, 33, 55, 22]
b = [3, 2, 0, 1]
надо что список а был расположен по значениям из списка b:
22, 55, 11, 33

Comment: А какая логика?) Или вы перепутали и должно быть все таки 55, 22, 33, 11?

Comment: Нет, у меня таких как b- 24 штуки. И надо с одним списком ,как a, сделать так 24 раза. Представьте что b это индекс к списку а. И в таком порядке надо разложить

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно использовать [генератор списков](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions), если не важно сохранить исходный объект `a`

```
a = [11, 33, 55, 22]
b = [3, 2, 0, 1]

a = [a[i] for i in b]

print(a) # [22, 55, 11, 33]
```

А если важно не потерять ссылку на `a`, вместо прямого присваивания, последовательно переносить элементы в цикле:

```
for i, val in enumerate([a[i] for i in b]):
    a[i] = val
```